# Make a div-tag come in bottom another div-tag

Tags: html, css

How is it possible to make a divtag to come under another divtag?

I want to make a bottom list

Comment: You should provide more details.

Comment: if this involves DOM manipulation plase also specify which js library has your page included (if any)

Comment: You may want to change the title also.  :l

Comment: Define "bottom list" and we can start helping.. until then it's pure guess.

Answer (score 1):

The <div> tag has a "display" style of "block" by default.  If you want to stack <div> tags, they you should only have to do the following:


`<div>
The content of this div will reside above.
</div>

<div>
the content of this div tag will reside below.
</div>`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that i understand your question. But here is a try.

Give the first div the css property `clear:left`

Here is a inline example:

`<div style="clear:left">first</div>
<div>second</div>`